# Upload Excel sheet into apex application

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I need to load data from Excel into a table . i.e. upload excel from Apex application and then insert this data into Oracle database table. I have been advised to avoid plugin so am looking for Oracle Apex processed using which I can do this.
I tried to do this with page in Apex in type data loading ,
I created a table to insert the data from the Excel sheet into and  created an Excel sheet to be uploaded
but I had an error no data found in sheet 1

Any advice/steps/links to information would be very helpful.

Th file to be loaded is .xlsx

Comment: "Data Loading" it is; at least, that's what I would be using. As Apex said **"no data found in sheet 1"**, all I can say is that Apex tried to load data, but there was nothing to load so it informed you about it.

Comment: How many rows are we talking about? If hundreds or less, use Excel string concatenation to create INSERT statements per row and then copy and paste that into your Oracle client. If tens of thousands or more, there are many methods, but perhaps a simple one available to many is to import the Excel into MS Access which has the ability to connect to Oracle and push data to it as a second step.

Answer (score 1):

It also depends if you want this to form part of an end-user application.

If not, then you can use an excel to construct your SQL statements, as suggested by Paul W.
Or you can use the SQL Workshop - Data Loader, as described here:
https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/post/quick-and-easy-data-loading-with-apex-191

If you want it as part of an application, you can use a file browse item to select the spreadsheet, then use the apex_data_parser package to convert the content.
https://blogs.oracle.com/apex/post/super-easy-csv-xlsx-json-or-xml-parsing-about-the-apex-data-parser-package

You query could look like this:

```
select line_number, col001, col002, col003, col004, col005, 
                    col006, col007, col008, col009, col010
                    -- more columns (col011 to col300) can be selected here.
  from apex_application_temp_files f, 
       table( apex_data_parser.parse(
                  p_content                     => f.blob_content,
                  p_add_headers_row             => 'Y',
                  p_max_rows                    => 500,
                  p_store_profile_to_collection => 'FILE_PARSER_COLLECTION',
                  p_file_name                   => f.filename ) ) p
 where f.name = :PX_FILE
```

The plugin that used to server this purpose was almost solely PL/SQL, and not really something to be deterred from using. But the concept is now baked into the APEX build.